# Selecting rows having more than one connection to another two tables

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have three tables:

```
table `customers` with columns `id`,`name`
table `contracts` with columns `id`, `customer_id`, `text`
table `phones` with columns `id`, customer_id`, `number`
```

I'd like to select customers which has more than 1 contracts AND more than one phone numbers. I tried to do the folowing:

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` 

WHERE 

 (SELECT count(*) FROM `contracts` WHERE `customer_id` = `id`) > 1 
  AND 
 (SELECT count(*) FROM `phones` WHERE `customer_id` = `id`) > 1
```

But it produces error `#1054 - Unknown column 'customer_id' in 'where clause'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT customers.* FROM customers

INNER JOIN
(

  SELECT customer_id, count(*) AS count FROM contracts GROUP BY customer_id 

  HAVING count > 1

) AS contracts

ON customers.id = contracts.customer_id

INNER JOIN

(

  SELECT customer_id, count(*) AS count FROM phones GROUP BY customer_id 

  HAVING count > 1

) AS phones

ON customers.id = phones.customer_id
```

Comment: Thank you and @Abdul for your answer! But actually I need to select rows having more than one corresponding rows in TWO other tables. I thought that I will be able to scale your answer to my purpose by simply adding one more conditional statement but it doesn't work :( Should I edit my initail question to be more correct to my purpose? Or should I create a new one?

Comment: Please update your question to include all other tables and the conditional you want to apply on them. I will update my query accordingly

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
SELECT a.id,a.name , COUNT(b.id) AS no_of_contracts
FROM 
customers a JOIN contracts b ON a.id = b.customer_id 
GROUP BY a.id HAVING no_of_contracts > 1
```